# Datastore Emulator: DatastoreGrpcStub requires a local gRPC installation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, virtualenv

We're running App Engine standard, and I'm trying to migrate to the datastore emulator, but when I enable it with `--support_datastore_emulator=True`, I get the error:

```
  File ".../platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/datastore_grpc_stub.py", line 82, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('The DatastoreGrpcStub requires a local gRPC '
RuntimeError: The DatastoreGrpcStub requires a local gRPC installation, which is not found.
```

---

The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator) warns about this problem, and their solution is to run from inside a virtualenv, but when I run `dev_appserver.py` from inside a virtualenv I get the following error:

```
File ".../platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 21, in <module>
    import logging
ImportError: No module named logging
```

---

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Even though you probably did it, I will still ask - did you run `pip install logging`? Also, could you post the `pip freeze` output for both normal environment and virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I did, and somehow the problem remains the same...
I have a support ticket open with Google, and they confirmed that there's a bug with Grpc (apparently occurring on specific Linux environments).